# Command line marker not found

Tags: linux, command-line, openwrt

I'am having this problem when building openwrt:

```
Command line marker not found!
make[5]: *** [kernel_prepare] Error 255
```

After analysing i find that the problem comes from `tools/patch-image/src/patch-cmdline.c` :

```
for (p = ptr; p < (ptr + search_space); p += 4) {
    if (memcmp(p, "CMDLINE:", 8) == 0) {
        found = 1;
        p += 8;
        break;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Command line marker not found!\n");
    goto err3;
}

memset(p, 0, CMDLINE_MAX - 8);
strcpy(p, argv[2]);
msync(p, CMDLINE_MAX, MS_SYNC|MS_INVALIDATE);
ret = 0;
```

What I have understand is that `patch-cmdline.c` tries to find the attribute `CMDLINE` in the `tmp/vmlinux-alfa-nx` and once found "patches" the command line.

Questions:

- What is the purpose of vmlinux-alfa-nx, it's not the kernel image:

  file vmlinux-alfa-nx
  vmlinux-alfa-nx: data
- Visibly the issue comes from tmp/vmlinux-alfa-nx, how can I change it so that it contains "CMDLINE"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it's probable that you're not defining correctly a target to build OpenWRT. `CMDLINE` is a variable that holds the command line used to load the kernel.

You might want to read [this documentation article](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/techref/process.boot), or [this post](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?id=883) in OpenWRT forums.